# AWS Linux configuring mysql with tomcat7

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I've installed Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5.5 on my AWS Linux micro instance. I'm trying to figure out how to configure Tomcat 7 to communicate with MySQL, but have had no luck. I've always been a Glassfish user, so it was pretty simple to do through the GUI, however with Tomcat, I'm not sure how to configure this.

I've looked at the Apache documentation on Tomcat 7, but found myself even more confused. I do not know where the files are I need to edit and I do not know what to edit them with. Do I need to install a MySQL driver? Do I use JDBC or JNDI? My app is a Tapestry5 app that uses Hibernate, so I'm not sure if that matters.

Does anybody know of a nice guide or could provide me with example code on how to do this? Just for the record, I only have a couple hours behind the wheel of Linux, so I'm very green when it comes to anything Linux related.

**UPDATE**

I found the following default configuration

```
<!--    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
-->
```

I'm using hibernate and in the hibernate.cfg.xml I'm using the following

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/mydatabase</property>
```

I commented out the above resource and added the following, but this also doesn't seem to work. I also noticed I no longer have access to the tomcat manager either.

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/mydatabase"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"
            username="root"
            password="password"
/>
```

I added the following to the context.xml file

```
<ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                name="jdbc/mydatabase"
                global="jdbc/mydatabase"
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong with this configuration?

I'm getting the following exception

> root cause
>
> ```
> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'ValueEncoderSource': Error invoking service
> ```
>
> contribution method
>   org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateModule.contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration,
>   boolean, HibernateSessionSource, Session, TypeCoercer, PropertyAccess,
>   LoggerSource): Exception constructing service
>   'HibernateSessionSource': Error invoking constructor public
>   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl(org.slf4j.Logger,java.util.List):
>   Could not find datasource
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mydatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the Tomcat 6 using JNDI, but I dont remember the exact configuration settings, but one thing is sure you need to use JNDI.

Comment: @JeenavDongre You may not know this answer, but curious as for why I need to add configuration settings to my WEB-INF/web.xml with tomcat, but with Glassfish, this is unnecessary? In Glassfish you can configure the JDBC to work with the database through it's GUI with no settings in the application other than the datasource within hibernate.cfg.xml. I use Jetty for local developing, so I'm concerned with the fact tomcat settings within the app might break jetty from running. I'm not sure this is the case, but my concerns.

Comment: First you ll not have any kind of GUI to configure your database manually. Here is a example of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Context configuration

Configure the JNDI DataSource in Tomcat by adding a declaration for your
resource to your Context.

Open the context.xml which is located at the Tomcat configuration (conf) folder.

For Example: (This path might be differ for your tomcat instance)

D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf

Add the following Resource entry with your database properties.

</Context>

--------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------

<Resource name="jdbc/Foofys" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"

maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"

username="root" password="pradeep" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foofys"/>

</Context>

Bolded attributes should be as per your database configurations.

2. web.xml configuration

Open the context.xml which is located at the Tomcat configuration (conf) folder.

For Example: (This path might be differ for your tomcat instance)

D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"

version="2.4">

<resource-ref>

<description>DB Connection</description>

<res-ref-name>jdbc/Foofys</res-ref-name>

<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

<res-auth>Container</res-auth>

</resource-ref>

-----------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------

</web-app>

3. Copy the My SQL database driver into the tomcat common
libraries folder.

For Example: (This path might be differ for your tomcat instance)

D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat5.5\common\lib

mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Jeevan, I won't be able to test this until tonight, but I do have a few more quick questions. I'm assuming web.xml is the xml file located within the app under WEB-INF? Would you happen to know why resource-ref is required within web.xml for tomcat, but not required with glassfish? Also, I notice your handling your database connection in context.xml rather than server.xml, what is the difference? I may have a couple more questions later this evening after giving this a whirl, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in a project. I forgot to place jdbc mysql connector in lib folder of apache tomcat. [Mysql JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Later I added the file to lib folder and got rid of the exception.